# How many surjective functions are there in this set of mappings?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I have the set of mappings $\mathcal F = \{f\,|\,f : \{1,2,3,4\} \to \{a,b,c\}\}$.

What is the total number of all surjective mappings $f\in\mathcal F$ with $f(4) = c$ ?

Comment: How many functions are there in total?  How many functions are not surjective (i.e not hitting an element). Hint: Inclusion - exclusion

Answer (score 1):

The fibers (i.e. non-empty sets of the form $f^{-1}(\{b\})$) of every function $f:A\to B$ form a partition of $A$.

In this case $|B|=3$ so if function $f$ is surjective then there are exactly $3$ fibers, and the question rises: how many distinct partitions are there on set $A$ that have $3$ elements?

If $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ then this is not difficult to find: there are $\binom42=6$.

An example of such a partition is $\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$.

Every partition induces $3!=6$ distinct surjections.

Using the example again we can have $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{1,2\}$, $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{3\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{c\})=\{4\}$ as an example of a surjective function, and here we can arrange the $a,b,c$ in $3!=6$ ways.

So we come eventually to a total of $6\cdot6=36$ surjections.

---

**edit** (I overlooked the extra condition that $f(4)=c$):

But wait, we have $f(4)=c$. That means that the element of the partition that contains element $4$ has allready found its destiny in the sense that all elements in it must be sent to $c$. Then there are $2!=2$ possibilities instead of $3!=6$. So there are $6\cdot2=12$ surjections with $f(4)=c$.

Comment: Note the condition $f(4)=c$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thank you. I overlooked.

Comment: @ajotatxe It has been repaired now.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to find the number of surjective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy the condition $f(4) = c$.

Since $f(4) = c$, $c$ is in the range.  Therefore, we can find the number of surjective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ by subtracting the number of functions which do not have $a$ or $b$ in the range from the number of functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy the condition $f(4) = c$.

How many functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ satisfy the condition $f(4) = c$?

Functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy $f(4) = c$ are determined by how we assign $f(1)$, $f(2)$, and $f(3)$.  Since there are three choices in the codomain for each of these three values, there are $3^3$ functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy the condition $f(4) = c$.

How many of these functions do not have $a$ in the range?

If $a$ is not in the range, there are two ways to assign $f(1)$, $f(2)$, and $f(3)$.  Hence, there are $2^3$ functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy $f(4) = c$ and that do not have $a$ in the range.

How many of these functions do not have $b$ in the range?

By symmetry, there are also $2^3$ functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy $f(4) = c$ and that do not have $b$ in the range.

Notice that if we subtract both those functions that do not have $a$ in the range and those functions that do not have $b$ in the range from the total, we will have subtracted those functions that have neither $a$ nor $b$ in the range twice, once for each way we could have excluded one of the elements from the range.

How many functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy $f(4) = c$ have neither $a$ nor $b$ in the range?

The only such function is the constant function $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = f(4) = c$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of surjective functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{a, b, c\}$ that satisfy the condition $f(4) = c$ is $3^3 - 2 \cdot 2^3 + 1^3 = 12$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: in order for $f$ to be surjective you have to make sure that the image of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ contains $\{a,b\}$ (actually, given your assumption $f$ will be surjective *if and only if* $\{a,b\}\subset f(\{1,2,3\})$). Can you find the number of ways of doing this? (Note that $\{c\}$ is also allowed to be contained in the image of $\{1,2,3\}$).

Comment: I don't get the correct answer but this is my approach ...
You have 3 objects which are the elements in the set $\{1,2,3\}$ which you want to distribute into 3 "boxes" given by each element in $\{a,b,c\}$ such that box $a$ and box $b$ contain at least 1 object.
This would be the same as finding the number of solutions to 
$x_1 + x_ 2 + x_3 = 3$ with the restrictions $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_2 \geq 1$ where $x_1$ is number of elements in box $a$, and $x_2$ is number of elements in box $b$.
Doing this I get 3 ways, that is 3 surjective functions, but that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

Number of functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{c\}$: $1$

$n=$ number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{a,c\}$=number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{b,c\}$=$\big($number of functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{a,c\}\big)-2$

$m=$ number of functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{a,b,c\}$.

Answer: $m-2n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$ for some $x,y$ as you already have $f(4)=c$ and the function is surjective.  There remaining value can be any of $a,b,c$. So that gives $3\times 2 \times 3=18$ possibilities

But that counts some patterns twice, such as $(1,2,3,4) \to (a,b,a,c)$ and more generally those with two $a$s or two $b$s.  In fact $3\times 2= 6$ are double counted

So there are $18-6=12$ possible functions meeting your constraints.  They are:

```
(1,2,3,4) -> (a,b,a,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (a,b,b,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (b,a,a,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (b,a,b,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (a,a,b,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (b,b,a,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (a,b,c,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (b,a,c,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (a,c,b,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (b,c,a,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (c,a,b,c)
(1,2,3,4) -> (c,b,a,c)
```